# How I can add attribute to certain type of input

Tags: jquery

I want add attribute to all the inputs of type="text" only ?? 
how I can make this by Jquery or css ?

```
<input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" class="field-1">
<input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" class="field-2">
<input type="submit" value="Send" class="button">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with js.

You need to add JQuery to work.

```
$("input[type='text']").attr("attr-name","attr-value");
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use [jQuery attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)

```
$('input[type=text]').attr('attrubuteName', newValue)
```